# Pickle dump Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

This is a question from a lazy man.

I have 4 million rows of pandas DataFrame and would like to save them into smaller chunks of pickle files.

Why smaller chunks?
To save/load them quicker.

My question is: 
1) Is there a better way (in-built function) to save them in smaller pieces than manually chunking them using np.array_split?

2) Is there any graceful way of gluing them together when I read the chunks other than manually gluing them together?

Please Feel free to suggest any other data type suited for this job other than pickle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using this for a dataframe of size 7,000,000 x 250

Use hdfs [DOCUMENTATION](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5))
df
```

[image]

```
df.to_hdf('myrandomstore.h5', 'this_df', append=False, complib='blosc', complevel=9)

new_df = pd.read_hdf('myrandomstore.h5', 'this_df')
new_df
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the goal is to save and load quickly you should look into [using sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) rather than raw text pickling. If your computer chokes when you ask it to write 4 million rows you can specify a chunk size.

From there you can query slices with std. SQL.